# Where should I put my logic for initializing state in a Redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am developing a React + Redux minesweeper application.

Here is a screenshot of the general look of my directory structure...
[image]

In my reducer.js file, I  have a bunch of logic that creates an object that represents the initial state that the reducer uses.

I feel like this is not a good place to put the logic that initializes the state because it's not a good separation of concerns. Where is a good place to factor this code out? Should I have another file that's responsible for generating initial state or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could confine the code that generates the initial state to its own file, say `initialState.js`, and put it next to your `reducer.js`. From `initialState.js` the generated object could be exported

```
export default {... the initial state here ... };
```

And then from `reducer.js` you could

```
import initialState from './initialState';
```

Comment: Yes but is that common practice?

Comment: Common practice is to modularize your code, stick to the _Single responsibility principle_, and make code easier to maintain. Separating the initialization of the state into its own module (file), will help achieve these. As such, I would call this 'common practice'.

Comment: Yeah but I mean specifically in a react + redux application and specifically with respect to my current directory structure, where would be a good place to put it

Comment: A good place to put the new file would be next to `reducer.js` since the two are closely related.